# Stacking an array with overlapping indices. Looking for a vectorized way over loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am looking for a vectorized way to loop over array indices to vertically stack them in groups with overlapping indices.
To give a gist of what I am trying to achieve:

Given a list **[1,2,3,4,5,6]**, an *interval variable* of value 2 and an *overlap variable* of value 1. 
The output should look something like this: **[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]**

However, the data I have is in the shape of **1560x2x87236**, where 1560 are the subjects, 2x87236 are **x,y** trajectories. So for each subject I have 87236 x points and 87326 y points. 
Maintaining the dimension 2 that represents xs and ys through the transformation is crucial.

---

To simplify representation:

Suppose I have an ndarray:

> arr

```
array([[[35, 33, 34, 42, 32, 30],
        [22, 38, 29, 33, 25, 14]],
       [[17, 25, 39, 17, 41, 22],
        [22, 13, 14, 31, 20, 38]],
       [[30, 10, 33, 25, 38, 26],
        [28, 27, 19, 27, 43, 13]]])
```

> arr.shape

```
(3, 2, 6)
```

What I am trying to do is stack this array in groups or intervals of 3 with overlapping indices (overlapping by 1 index).
The output looks something like this:

> stacked_arr

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[35., 33., 34.],
        [22., 38., 29.]],

       [[34., 42., 32.],
        [29., 33., 25.]],

       [[17., 25., 39.],
        [22., 13., 14.]],

       [[39., 17., 41.],
        [14., 31., 20.]],

       [[30., 10., 33.],
        [28., 27., 19.]],

       [[33., 25., 38.],
        [19., 27., 43.]]])
```

> stacked_arr.shape

```
(7, 2, 3)
```

This is the function I have written that achieves the above result:

```
def overlap_stack(data, padwith, interv, overlapby):
    sub = 0

    # Initialise: 1 bcuz for a sub, 2 bcuz of x,y
    stacked = cp.zeros(shape=(1, 2, interv))
    while sub < data.shape[0]:
        idx: int
        for idx in range(0, data.shape[2], interv - overlapby):

            # grouping with overlaps
            stack = cp.expand_dims(data[sub, :, idx: idx + interv], axis=0)

            # pad to cope with unequal length
            if (stack.shape[2]) < interv:
                stack = cp.pad(stack, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (0, interv - stack.shape[2])), 'constant',
                               constant_values=padwith)

            # stacking all together
            stacked = cp.vstack((stacked, stack))


        sub += 1
    return stacked
```

It takes over 8 to 10hours to transform the array of 1560x2x87236. I would really appreciate if you could help me to speed up this process in any way.

Comment: Is that padding with zeros as the starting block needed?

Comment: Yes, any constant value. The way i have used it is , np.pad will only pad to zeros or any constant value at 3 dimension, column wise, will ignore rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are familiar with [numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html), but here's a solution using it:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def overlap_stack(data, interv, overlapby):
    A = np.vstack(data)

    window_size = (data.shape[1], interv)
    strides = (window_size[0], interv - overlapby)

    output_strides = (strides[0]*A.strides[0], strides[1]*A.strides[1]) + A.strides

    output_shape = ((A.shape[0] - window_size[0])//strides[0] + 1,
                    (A.shape[1] - window_size[1])//strides[1] + 1) + window_size

    return as_strided(A, shape=output_shape, strides=output_strides).reshape(-1, *output_shape[2:])
```

I have ignored the padding because I am not sure how you want it (you can add it by yourself though).

For example:

```
data = np.array([[[35, 33, 34, 42, 32, 30],
                  [22, 38, 29, 33, 25, 14]],
                 [[17, 25, 39, 17, 41, 22],
                  [22, 13, 14, 31, 20, 38]],
                 [[30, 10, 33, 25, 38, 26],
                  [28, 27, 19, 27, 43, 13]]])

overlap_stack(data, 3, 1)

array([[[35, 33, 34],
        [22, 38, 29]],

       [[34, 42, 32],
        [29, 33, 25]],

       [[17, 25, 39],
        [22, 13, 14]],

       [[39, 17, 41],
        [14, 31, 20]],

       [[30, 10, 33],
        [28, 27, 19]],

       [[33, 25, 38],
        [19, 27, 43]]])
```

Note that for an array of shape `(1560, 2, 87236)` this will be pretty fast, but it takes a lot of memory.